# Deleting all local calendar events works, but triggers an error that too many events has deleted

Tags: android, calendar

I use the following method to delete all events on a google calendar locally (ICS & JB):

```
public void deleteAll(){
    String selection = "(" + CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID + " = ?)";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(this.calId) };
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    int rows = cr.delete(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, selection, selectionArgs);
    Log.d(TAG, rows + " events deleted");
}
```

It all works fine, but I get an annoying warning: Too many calendar deletes

```
Delete limit exceeded

 There are 21 deleted items for Calendar, account
 xxxxx.xxxxx@gmail.com.  What would you like to do?" 

Delete the items. 
Undo the deletes.  
Do nothing for now.
```

What is the reason for the error to be shown, and does anyone know a way to avoid it?
I'm using the HTC One-X

Regards R

Comment: Have you tried to delete a particular/specific event only from your calendar? If deleting 1-by-1 works without getting the warning, I'm thinking to iterate the events and delete it 1-by-1.

Comment: I can confirm that trying to delete 1-by-1 by event id does not work either. Any time you try to delete enough events that trigger that message (not knowing what the limit is) it still happens regardless of deleting 1-by-1 or all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times, it's very annoying! This is unfortunately a known and ongoing issue. There's an [existing bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28862) on it, but it still hasn't been corrected.

To fix the issue, you have to clear your local calendar cache.

To do so, do the following on your device:

**Stock Android:**

```
Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Calendar Storage > Clear data
```

**HTC Sense:**

```
Settings > Apps > All > Calendar Storage > Clear data
```

Once you do that, the problem will go away.

Comment: That's great, but my app's users shouldn't be expected to do this, should they? I specifically don't want them to see the notification warning, since what they're doing they really did want to do.. no sense in bothering them about it again. Is there a way to automatically prompt to clear these caches?

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing that can be done programmatically to silence the prompt; while you can clear app data programmatically, you can only clear _your own_ app's data, not Google Calendar. 

It's a bug.

Comment: For me (Android 4.0.4) path to clear data was Settings > Device > Storage > Internal Storage > Apps > All > Calendar Storage (NOT Calendar) > Storage > Clear Data.   HTH someone. Brewmanz